# How to delete element of an array of structs?

Tags: c++

I have a program that has to choose between 10 bins of parts. Once the user have chosen a bin, the program ask if you want to either add or remove parts.my problem is when I am trying to add or remove from a single bin it adds and removes from all the bins.

```
struct Inventory
{
    char description[35];
    int num;
};

Inventory parts[Number_Bins] = {
    {"Valve", 10},
    {"Bearing", 5},
    {"Bushing", 15},
    {"Coupling", 21},
    {"Flange", 7},
    {"Gear", 5},
    {"Gear Housing", 5},
    {"Vacuum Gripper", 25},
    {"Cable", 18},
    {"Rod", 12}
};
```

This is my function to remove parts. I have another to add parts and it is similar. I could create like 10 of this for each element of the array but that is not the point.

```
void RemoveParts(Inventory bins[])
{
    int e = 10;
    int enter2;
    cout << "Enter how many you want to remove\n";
    cin >> enter2;
    if (enter2 < 0)
    {
        cout << "Negative Values are not legal. Try again\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < e; index++)
        {
            bins[index].num = bins[index].num - enter2;
        }
    }
}
```

I use a switch menu to pick up any bins. So there are 10 cases. Is there any way I can make it easier and write less code?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are looping through all the bins in here:

```
for (int index=0; index<e; index++){     
  bins[index].num = bins[index].num - enter2;
}
```

If you want to remove from a certain bin you have to tell your program which one.

From what I understand, you want to remove an entire bin...

To do this you have to remove the element from the array.

I suggest using either `std::vector<Inventory> parts(Number_Bins)` or `std::array<Inventory, 10> parts;` or even `std::list<Inventory> parts(Number_Bins)`. then set up that.

Then removing elements will be just by using remove

To remove from your `array` specifically you have to shift the entire array.

```
//where enter2 is the element we want to erase
for (int index=enter2-1; index<total_size; index++){     
  bins[index] = bins[index + 1]; 
}
// then reinit content of last element
bins[total_size-1] = 0;
```

I don't recommend this road at all, it makes **everything** harder, and that feels like an understatement. This is why:

- Now you have to check that setting the `Inventory` item to 0 successfully sets both variables to 0
- Now you have to keep track of the number of `Initialized` elements in the array
- You also need to track the size of the array

This is no `C++`, there is no encapsulation, no OOP, and this will likely force you to introduce `global` variables because you'll have to keep track of stuff.

Writing non scalable and non maintainable code is bad for your present, but most importantly, to your future.

Comment: what if I don't use vectors or std::list<Inventory> parts(Number_Bins). Is there any other way? what about the menu I crated with 10 cases. Can I do it in one case or something? I'm sorry  I kind of new in structures and I just want to know more ways to do this.

Comment: @user3019164, no you don't, I told you three different structures to do this differently, you want to stick to the way you are doing it. Check the edit

Comment: I don't know how to use vector or the other options. I guess I have to read about it.

Comment: @user3019164 keeping up with the best practices is essential to your development.